# how to calculate number of free tickets when total tickets is incremented by 3

Tags: jquery

I am working on a ticketing system. How to calculate total number of free tickets in following scenario using jquery:
when number of tickets is incremented by 3, number of free tickets is incremented by 1.

for example :
3 tickets, cost calculated for 2 tickets, 1 ticket is free.
6 tickets, cost calculated for 4 tickets, 2 ticket are free.
9 tickets, cost calculated for 6 tickets, 3 ticket are free.

Comment: how about `total / 3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method will calculate the total price by number of tickets * ticket price, then calculate how many free tickets there should be by rounding total number of tickets / 3 **down** (using [`floor()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_floor.asp)). You'll then remove that number * the ticket price from the total:

```
var numTickets = parseInt( $('#NumTickets').val() );          // your num tickets
var price = parseFloat( $('#Price').val().replace('$', '') ); // removing $ sign

var freeTickets = Math.floor(numTickets / 3);                 // calc num free tickets
var total = numTickets * price;                               // prelim total          
total -= freeTickets * price;                                 // remove free ticket values
```

**[Example:](http://jsfiddle.net/scrowler/v7jEC/)** ticket price $25:

```
1 ticket:  $25
2 tickets: $50
3 tickets: $50  (one free)
4 tickets: $75  (one free)
5 tickets: $100 (one free)
6 tickets: $100 (two free)
7 tickets: $125 (two free)
etc...
```